# full calendar, events holidays and own events

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to mix my own events and retrieve from google calendars the holidays for a given country. I have my API key etc..
I get my data from ajax calls, and build my events as

```
     my_events.push({title:name,
                start: moment(date_begin),
                end:moment(date_end)
          });
```

works perfectly. Now I want the holidays. In the demos of full calendar in github, i see the following code:

```
     googleCalendarApiKey: 'xxx',
     // US Holidays
     events: 'usa__en@holiday.calendar.google.com',
```

It works (with my own key of course).

But now, I cannot understand how  see both my_events and the holidays.
I tried my_events.push({'usa__en@holiday.calendar.google.com'})
does not work.

How do I do that ?

Another question is, I am not in USA, i would like to get European countries holidays. Does anybody know if there is a similar address for france, italy etc ? I tried fr, fra__fr, it, ita__it etc but always got a "notFound"

Thanks for any pointer and explanation

Comment: I found the calendars for France (french__fr),Italy, Germany and Spain. By trial and error, is there any official list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple event sources with fullcalendar - have your event source and then add one for the holiday calendar(s)

Here's a fiddle for the below code (you have to have an API key!) https://jsfiddle.net/5x2dL5Ls/

```
/* Modified from http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.6.0/demos/gcal.html */

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

  // THIS KEY WON'T WORK IN PRODUCTION!!!
  // To make your own Google API key, follow the directions here:
  // http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/
  googleCalendarApiKey: 'PUT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE',

/* For demo purposes, our hard-coded event source information */
  defaultDay: '2016-02-01',
  events: [{
    title: 'This is a non-google-holiday event',
    start: '2016-02-16',
    end:   '2016-02-20'
  }],
/* For demo purposes */

  eventClick: function(event) {
    // opens events in a popup window
    window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
    return false;
  },

  loading: function(bool) {
    $('#loading').toggle(bool);
  }

});

$('#addSource').click(function() {
  var source = $('#holidayCalendar').val();
  // $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', source);
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', source);
});

$('#removeSource').click(function() {
  var source = $('#holidayCalendar').val();
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', source);
});
```

I didn't find good documentation for a complete list of holiday sources, so I made one by scraping data from "Browse Interesting Calendars" link on calendar.google.com that looked like this

```
[/* ... */,    {
    "title":"Holidays in United States",
    "type":"calendar",
    "did":"ZW4udXNhI2hvbGlkYXlAZ3JvdXAudi5jYWxlbmRhci5nb29nbGUuY29t",
    "country":"US"
}, /* ... */]
```

Then appending the "**did**" from that data onto this url, example USA holidays

https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=ZW4udXNhI2hvbGlkYXlAZ3JvdXAudi5jYWxlbmRhci5nb29nbGUuY29t

and scraping that page for "cids":{"the_creator_is_in_here": and extracting it...
Hackish, but got a list of Calendars.

For languages, you can try changing the 'en.' to another language prefix.

For example "Holidays in Japan" can be rendered in English or Japanese:

- en.japanese#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com
- ja.japanese#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com

Comment: thanks a lot! got it working in my code.And I will do as you did, to find the calendars not in english but in their own languages.

Comment: @smod In fact your list is perfect! changing en by the language code of that country - et voilà, the calendars display in that language ! fantastic ! thanks again

Comment: Good deal. I was just writing a comment that for languages, trying 'es' for spanish, 'ja' for japanese, 'en' english, 'fr' for french, 'it' italian, etc. seems like it works out OK.