# How to add google US holidays to my calendar?

Tags: coldfusion, fullcalendar

I have a perfectly working fullCalendar that displays leave time on a calendar (via my ColdFusion .cfc)

```
<html>

<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css" />
<script src="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/gcal.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                if (title) {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                        {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            allDay: allDay
                        },
                        true // make the event "stick"
                    );
                }
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            editable: true,
            googleCalendarApiKey:'my_api_key',
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/events?key=my_api_key',
            events: "getLeaveRequests_byDept.cfc?method=getMyData",
            timeFormat: ' ', // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
            eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                    '(should probably update your database)');


            }           
        });

    });
</script> 

<title>Calendar</title></head>

<body>

<div id='calendar'>
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

As you can see, I added in the following: the gcal.js file (google calendar javascript) and the following two lines to try and add holidays along with my other dates:

```
googleCalendarApiKey:'my_api_key',
url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/events?key=my_api_key',
```

My dates still display fine, but the holidays do not display on the calendar? Any ideas?

Here is my attempt to use "eventSources" instead of "events"

```
<html>

<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css" />
<script src="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/gcal.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                if (title) {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                        {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            allDay: allDay
                        },
                        true // make the event "stick"
                    );
                }
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            editable: true,
            googleCalendarApiKey: 'my_api_key',
        eventSources: [
        {
            "getLeaveRequests_byDept.cfc?method=getMyData"
        },
        {
            googleCalendarId: 'efgh5678@group.calendar.google.com'
        }
    ]
});

    });
</script> 

<title>Calendar</title></head>

<body>

<div id='calendar'>
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Here is the final code that worked:

```
<html>

<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css" />
<script src="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/gcal.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                if (title) {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                        {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            allDay: allDay
                        },
                        true // make the event "stick"
                    );
                }
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            editable: true,
            nextDayThreshold:'00:00:00',
            // display Leave Requests plus Holidays from Google calendar
            googleCalendarApiKey: '* my api key *',
            eventSources: [ 'getLeaveRequests.cfc?method=getMyData', 'en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com' ],
            timeFormat: ' ', // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
            eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                    '(should probably update your database)');
            }           
        });

    });
</script> 

<title>Calendar</title></head>

<body>

<div id='calendar'>
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

I had to add in the gcal.js, add in my google api key, change "events" to "eventSources", and use "[ ]" brackets instead of "{}"

Comment: This answer may help for adding a source later http://stackoverflow.com/a/35442698/5360631 and/or try **eventSources: { 'getLeaveRequests_byDept.cfc?method=getMyData', 'en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com' }** vs **events** https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventSources/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final code that worked:
I had to add in the gcal.js, add in my google api key, change "events" to "eventSources", and use "[ ]" brackets instead of "{}"

```
<html>

<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.css" />
<script src="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="../fullcalendar-3.1.0/gcal.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end, allDay) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                if (title) {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                        {
                            title: title,
                            start: start,
                            end: end,
                            allDay: allDay
                        },
                        true // make the event "stick"
                    );
                }
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
            editable: true,
            nextDayThreshold:'00:00:00',
            // display Leave Requests plus Holidays from Google calendar
            googleCalendarApiKey: '* my api key *',
            eventSources: [ 'getLeaveRequests.cfc?method=getMyData', 'en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com' ],
            timeFormat: ' ', // uppercase H for 24-hour clock
            eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                    '(should probably update your database)');
            }           
        });

    });
</script> 

<title>Calendar</title></head>

<body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding the google credentials, is not sufficient - you already have your "events" defined, so fullCalendar will use those. Effectively what you've got here is multiple event sources, so use that feature:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //...all your other config...then:
    googleCalendarApiKey: '<YOUR API KEY>',
    eventSources: [
        {
            "getLeaveRequests_byDept.cfc?method=getMyData"
        },
        {
            googleCalendarId: 'efgh5678@group.calendar.google.com'
        }
    ]
});
```

See the docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/ for even more detail on how to configure Google Calendar with fullCalendar, including examples of multiple event sources.

Also I don't know where you got the idea that you could provide a "url" property - it's not defined anywhere in the docs, and has no effect. For Google calendar, The API key and calendar ID is sufficient. If the calendar is not actually yours, then you need to scrape the ID - I haven't tried it but the answer referred to in the comments ([full calendar, events holidays and own events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35440015/full-calendar-events-holidays-and-own-events/35442698#35442698) for the record) suggests a method to discover IDs of public calendars.

Comment: I have tried multiple ways of adding in your suggestion, but the calendar then displays a blank page? (see my edited entry above that shows what I tried) I'm not sure how to update my code to use "eventSources" instead of "events"? ps: this is the link to use url: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/

Comment: you do it exactly as I've shown - replace your "events" property with "eventSources" structured as I've shown. Each of the items in the eventSources array should resolve to a list of events, as if you'd specified it directly using "events". What you've shown looks like it should be fine. P.S. If you were using the addEventSource method you've linked to, you'd specify "url" as the argument to that method, not as a property of the original setup of the calendar. And your code doesn't call that method.

Comment: Still stuck with a blank page? Not sure what else to try. My updated code shown above gives me a blank page. thanks for the help, anyway.

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser console? Can you create a JSFiddle which demonstrates your issue? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks to ADyson and @smcd, this is now working great using "getSources" See my updated code above.

Comment: @jlig - If you think the final/full code would be helpful to others, post it as a separate "answer", rather than an edit. So it is more visible to future searchers.  You can still accept and/or up vote this answer if it helped you solved the problem.